# Controlling automatic conversion from ASCII to EBCDIC via xlc fgets() in USS

Tags: c, ascii, mainframe, zos, ebcdic

I have an application on z/OS USS that happily reads EBCDIC (IBM-1047) and ASCII (ISO8859-1) files that are tagged with either encoding into `char[]` buffers. When started from a shell, the C runtime will automatically convert the file contents in `fgets()` into EBCDIC for the program to use. This allows comparisons with literals encoded natively in EBCDIC.

However, when the program is run via Jenkins (Java JVM 1.8), the automatic conversion is suppressed and `fgets()` returns data unchanged, so ASCII. I have tried supplying every environment variable in the user's `.profile` and `/etc/profile` to the JVM, and verified that they are in the program's `envp`.

Does anyone know where the control of this function is documented or available?

Comment: Can you post your locale variables, ex. `LC_COLLATE` or preferably all? From the "application on z/OS" and from jenking environment, if somehow available? What do you use for string comparisons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the ways of controlling automatic conversion is `_BPXK_AUTOCVT=ON`  This [article](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.4.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r4.cbcpx01/setenv.htm) here describes the issue on more detail.

Here is a snippet:

[image]

[image]

Comment: That was it. Thank you.